# OnPrem TFS 2015.1 vNext - What step to Release to on premises IIS server?

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, release-management, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to use TFS 2015.1 on premise to build a CI pipeline for our dev & uat.  I've created a vNext CI build, which builds fine.  But when I want to add a deploy step for on prem IIS server, I only then see Azure Web Deployment options.

Ideally I wanted to add a step which uses the existing deploy (MS Deploy) profiles, which I'm able to use from VS2015 directly, using 'Publish'.  However I see no option to do so.

How can I deploy the latest build to internal dev servers (not Azure)?  I would like to use the MS Deploy option, unless there's a better way of doing it?

The fact that their is no option to starts to make me think there's probably a different way to accomplish it!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you in a position to upgrade to TFS 2015 Update 2 and use the new web-based release management tooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to upgrade to TFS 2015.2, [web-based Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/tfs2015-update2-vs#newrmtfs) came out with it that works similarly to Build vNext with flexible and open-source tasks. You can also customize tasks.

[Here's a link for IIS Web App Deployment from the vso-agent-task's GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeployment) where Microsoft stores updated versions of their tasks that you can download for web-based Build and Release Management.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be publishing a blog about web-based RM with TFS 2015 Update 2 or VSTS on [my website](http://pleasereleaseme.net/) in the next few weeks. To give you an idea though, the starting point (for a web application) is a folder in your web project called WebDeploy (no significance - any name will do) that contains a PowerShell DSC script that configures the server, deploys the web files and then replaces any tokenised configs. To give you an idea see [this](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-vsts-server-configuration-code-powershell-dsc/) post about how to use DSC to configure servers. (Only covers part of the final script though!) The next steps are:

1. In the build hub create a **Website** artifact - containing your web files and DSC script.
2. In the release hub for an environment use a **Windows Machine File Copy** task to deploy the artifact to a temp folder on the target node.
3. Then use a **PowerShell on Target Machines** task to execute the DSC script. After configuring the server the script copies the web files to their proper location, sorts out config using [xReleaseManagement](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xReleaseManagement/1.0.0.0) and cleans up the WebDeploy folder.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/examples/other-servers/net-to-vm) article for general details of the route I'm taking, but watch out as it has some errors eg the firewall instructions are incomplete (file and print sharing through the firewall needs to be enabled).

I can thoroughly recommend the PowerShell DSC route - I've had a few glitches but on the whole it feels very productive and the right way to be going.